# How to restart the Remote Desktop service on Windows 10, in case of error 1053?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, services

I've been having a problem with *restarting* Windows Remote Desktop service on Windows 10 - in particular, the restart process hangs when the Remote Desktop service tries to stop.

More specifically: after boot, I can open `services.msc`, and right-click "Remote Desktop Services" there, and click "Restart" - and it (along with "Remote Desktop Services UserMode Port Redirector") does restart (meaning it stops, then starts again).

Then, I establish a Remote Desktop session to the Windows 10 computer, everything works fine for couple of hours, and then for whatever reason, the server disconnects me from the session - and it is impossible to log in to the Windows 10 machine over Remote Desktop afterwards.

Going back to the Windows 10 machine after it has disconnected me from my RDP session, I try to again restart via `services.msc`, and right-click "Remote Desktop Services" there, and click "Restart" - however this time it hangs on the "stopping" part, and eventually (after a minute or so) it fails with:

> Services
>
> Windows could not start the Remote Desktop Services on Local Computer.
> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

And then one cannot retry the "Restart" of "Remote Desktop Services" after that, as it is greyed out, and the service remains stuck with "stopping" status.

What can I do to recover "Remote Desktop Services" at this point?

Answer (score 1):

After the crash of my Remote Desktop Session, the Windows 10 RDP "host" machine shows this in Administrator Command Prompt:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>qwinsta
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
 services                                    0  Disc
>console           user                      1  Active
 31c5fffffffff...                        65536  Listen
 7a78fffffffff...                        65537  Listen
 rdp-tcp                                 65538  Listen
```

I've tried using `rwinsta` to restart these, but that did not quite work:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>rwinsta 65536
If you reset this session, all users using this protocol will be logged off,
continue (n=no)? y
Could not reset session ID 65536, Error code 2
Error [2]:The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>rwinsta 65537
If you reset this session, all users using this protocol will be logged off,
continue (n=no)? y
Could not reset session ID 65537, Error code 2
Error [2]:The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>rwinsta 65538
If you reset this session, all users using this protocol will be logged off,
continue (n=no)? y

C:\WINDOWS\system32>qwinsta
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
 services                                    0  Disc
>console           user                      1  Active
                                         65536  Down
                                         65537  Down
 rdp-tcp                                 65538  Listen
```

Then, after trying to right-click/"Restart" the Remote Desktop Service, when the stopping process gets stuck, the status is this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>qwinsta
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
 services                                    0  Disc
>console           user                      1  Active
```

I haven't really confirmed this, but I think if the `rdp-tcp` part is gone, then you cannot establish a Remote Desktop connection.

In Administrator PowerShell, this is visible (found via https://green.cloud/docs/how-to-restart-remote-desktop-services-without-restarting-windows-server/):

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Restart-Service -Force -Name "TermService"
Restart-Service : Service 'Remote Desktop Services (TermService)' cannot be stopped due to the following error: Cannot
stop TermService service on computer '.'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Restart-Service -Force -Name "TermService"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Restart-Service
   ], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStopService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RestartServiceCommand
```

Here I used the approach I found in:

- https://woshub.com/killing-windows-services-that-hang-on-stopping/
- https://www.action1.com/how-to-remote-control-of-services-via-sc-psservice-mmc/

Back to Administrator Command Prompt:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc query TermService

SERVICE_NAME: TermService
        TYPE               : 30  WIN32
        STATE              : 3  STOP_PENDING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x1
        WAIT_HINT          : 0xea60
```

Note `sc query` does not give the PID, so use `sc queryex` instead:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc queryex TermService

SERVICE_NAME: TermService
        TYPE               : 30  WIN32
        STATE              : 3  STOP_PENDING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x1
        WAIT_HINT          : 0xea60
        PID                : 17372
        FLAGS              :
```

Gotcha - PID is 17372 - so just kill this as as task:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>taskkill /PID 17372 /F
SUCCESS: The process with PID 17372 has been terminated.
```

... and check the service status again:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc queryex TermService

SERVICE_NAME: TermService
        TYPE               : 30  WIN32
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
        PID                : 11340
        FLAGS              :

C:\WINDOWS\system32>qwinsta
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
 services                                    0  Disc
>console           user                      1  Active
 31c5fffffffff...                        65536  Listen
 7a78fffffffff...                        65537  Listen
 rdp-tcp                                 65538  Listen
```

Indeed, there is now a running service again, with a new PID.

And at this point, I can also right-click/"Restart" the Remote Desktop Service in `services.msc` - and it works fine again.